# SSIS Control Flow Task Not Executing After 2 Tasks With An Expression

Tags: ssis

I currently have an SSIS package that has a split in the branch that looks at a flag to see what to execute.  If its true it continues to task 1A, if its false it goes to task 1B.  Both tasks 1A and 1B move on to the same task.  When I run the entire package though it will correctly pick task 1A or 1B but then the package says its completed successfully and doesnt move on to the next task.  Is there something i need to configure so that it will execute the rest of the flow?  Please see the screen shot to see the actual flow.  It will not run the "Update Instock Velocity Codes" Container and below.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks,

Craig[image: Task Flow]

Comment: Try .. Right click one of the flow lines (`UPdates Velocity Codes If Last Friday Of Fiscal Month` or `Update CID With Current Celocity Codes` to `Update Instock Velocity Codes`) and select Edit. This will display the `Precedence Constraint Editor`. Change `Multiple constraints` and select `Logical OR, One constraint must evaluate to True`.

Comment: @t_m: post as answer, so creator can accept it as answer :)

Comment: @Matej .. Thanks, Posted as answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try ..

Right click one of the flow lines (`Updates Velocity Codes If Last Friday Of Fiscal Month or Update CID With Current Velocity Codes` to `Update Instock Velocity Codes`) and select Edit.

This will display the Precedence Constraint Editor.

Change `Multiple constraints` and select `Logical OR, One constraint must evaluate to True`

Comment: Thank you very much for this!! Really had me stumped for over an hour.